# C# String.Format to One Decimal Place

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm trying to format a toString to one decimal place but it keeps going to something like 21.0445445454. Here's the line of code please let me know what I'm doing wrong

```
 double heightInchToFoot = (12 * Convert.ToDouble(heightFtBox.Text)) +Convert.ToDouble(heightInchBox.Text);
        double bmi = (Convert.ToDouble(weightBox.Text) * 703) / (heightInchToFoot * heightInchToFoot);
        bmiDisplay.Text = String.Format("{0:0.0}", bmi.ToString());//This is the line of code I'm referring to
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm right but have you tried ############.# format??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the use of `bmi.ToString()` which converts the double to a string using the *default* [Double.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hfd35ad(v=vs.110).aspx) format/rules<sup>1</sup>. Because of that, the actual Format deals with a *string* (which doesn't understand decimal formatting) and not the actual double value.

Instead, it should be

```
String.Format("{0:0.0}", bmi)
```

or

```
bmi.ToString("0.0")
```

---

<sup>1</sup> From the documentation:

> The `Double.ToString()` method formats a Double value in the default ("G", or general) format of the current culture.